# Python Mock: Mocking a function inside the function I'm testing

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to use `Mock` to test the result returned from a function that retrieves a setting:

```
def apply_delta_to_date(original_date):
    delta = MySettings.get_delta()
    result_date = original_date + timedelta(delta)
    return result_date
```

When testing the `apply_delta_to_date` function, I'm trying to mock the call to `MySettings.get_delta` to simulate that its returning a specific result:

```
class TestAppyDelta():
    def setUp(self):
        self.MySettings = Mock()
        self.MySettings.get_delta = Mock(return_value=10)

    def test_apply_delta(self):
        result = apply_delta_to_date(today)
```

The problem is that I can't manage to "mock" the function call to `MySettings.get_delta()` which is inside the function that I really want to test.

How could I mock the result returned by an inner function inside the function I'm testing?

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523189/how-to-mock-nested-functions

Comment: This article explains why your mocking is not working https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is the patch.object context manager, which does exactly what you want: it takes a class and method, and allows you to define a custom return value.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from <your-time_utils-module> import apply_delta_to_date, MySettings


class TestAppyDelta():
    def test_apply_delta(self):
        with patch.object(MySettings, 'get_delta', return_value=10) as mock_method:
            result = apply_delta_to_date(today)

            # mock_method has many other useful assertions
            mock_method.assert_called_once()
```

Refer to the docs for more details https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

Answer (score 9):

You're not mocking the right thing at all. All you have done is to define a MySettings attribute *in your test class*. It is never called by anything.

You need to mock the reference to MySettings in the place where it is called. Assuming you're importing `apply_delta_to_date` from a module called `my_delta_module`:

```
@patch('my_delta_module.MySettings')
def test_apply_delta(self, mock_settings):
    mock_settings.get_delta.return_value = 10
    result = apply_delta_to_date(today)
```